# What makes this site unique?

Tags: discussion, publicity

If we're expecting members of this community to publicise it effectively, it might be helpful to give them a few tools to use.

One of these is our 'Elevator pitch' which has already been discussed: [What is the "Elevator pitch" for Genealogy SE?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/104).

Another might be a succinct explanation of what makes us different from all the other places on the Internet where one can go to get answers to genealogy and family history questions. Why ask here instead of (for example): [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index;_ylt=AspzkKWcBwPGOoRp4w2BqzOSxQt.;_ylv=3?sid=396546034&link=list); a specialised [mailing list](http://lists.rootsweb.ancestry.com/index/intl/WLS/DYFED.html) or [forum](https://www.evidenceexplained.com/forums/evidence-explained) ; the [user group](http://www.fhug.org.uk/cgi-bin/index.cgi) for your genealogy software of choice; or the website for a relevant [genealogy society](http://www.esog.org/queries.html). And I'm sure there are other kinds of places to go that I haven't thought of.

So: Why here? What do we offer that other sites don't?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out some stats proudly displayed on the home page:

> 537   questions
>
> 1,381 answers
>
> 99%   answered

**99%** answered. An average of over 3 answers per question. No other genealogy Q&A site or mailing list can offer that level of quality. You're probably even lucky to get that level of service if you pay for it.

Comment: Be a little careful what you try to do with statistics. There may have been 1381 answers but 690 of them have come from just nine (9) people. That is a small "community". An ecologist would say it was on the edge of extinction.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

> Genealogy SE draws in experts and enthusiasts in genealogy and family
>   history who are interested in learning and communicating at a
>   professional level. People ask quality questions that experts are
>   willing to answer. Experts are willing to come to answer the questions
>   because they are meaningful and of high quality.

Answer (score 0):

I've borrowed from @lkessler but widened the net a bit ...

> Genealogy SE draws in experts and enthusiasts in genealogy and family
>   history who are interested in learning and communicating at a
>   professional level. People ask quality questions that experts are
>   willing to answer. Experts are willing to come to answer the questions
>   because they are meaningful and of high quality.  Beginners are welcome
>   too but we should all search to see if our questions have already been
>   answered to avoid posting duplicates.

Second attempt:

> Genealogy SE draws in experts and enthusiasts in genealogy and 
>   family history who are interested in communicating at a
>   professional level. People ask quality questions that experts 
>   and beginners can answer and learn from.

Comment: I like the wider net -- we need to be welcoming to all levels of experience. Not certain, however, that the bit about checking for duplicates belongs in a 'sales pitch'.