# Is it OK to answer a question about available software products with information about a product you're associated with

Tags: discussion

I'm assuming it isn't but this probably needs clarifying sooner rather than later.

I'm not thinking here of a product you use, but one which you're involved in producing or marketing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has no one read the [FAQ](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)?

> ### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

It quite clearly spells out that:

1. Generally self-promotion is frowned upon
2. If some answers happen to be about your product, you **must** disclose your affiliation **in your answer**, not just your profile page.

This part of the FAQ is the same on every site. No different here.

Comment: OK, I've read the FAQ.

Comment: No one ever reads the FAQ, or at least we should operate under that assumption. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September

Comment: When you see posts with issues, just leave a kind comment and a link to the appropriate section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - I would think one could.  Many of the experts in this field are associated with some software product or other.  It would be rather strange to invite them to participate as an expert here, but tell them they could not comment on their software of choice - certainly they have made a decision to use that particular software for more than just the compensation.

As long as some sort of disclosure is made that indicates the affiliation, we'll benefit from the knowledge - as long as we're going to be answering software questions. See:

[Should we be allowing specific support questions for specific software or online genealogy sites?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-we-be-allowing-specific-support-questions-for-specific-software-or-online)

Comment: Yes, disclosure is the key.